не запускается docker контейнер на nuxt 3
есть dockerfile:


FROM node:20.13.1

RUN apk --no-cache --update add curl > /dev/null

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN rm -f package-lock.json

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 3030

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c" , "npm run dev"]



и docker-compose


    client:
        build: services/client
        image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_client:latest
        shm_size: "2gb"
        container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_client
        user: ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}
        volumes:
            - ${PROJECT_PATH}/client:/var/www:${WEBSITE_VOLUME_MODE}
        ports:
            - "3030:3000"
        networks:
            - website
        restart: "no"
        



после запуска и выполнения команды docker ps - контейне нету. В логах такие ошибки ERROR  (node:18) [DEP0180] DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created) и  ERROR  Cannot find module '/var/www/node_modules/unenv/dist/index.mjs' imported from /var/www/node_modules/nitropack/dist/index.mjs


npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.0
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.0
npm notice
npm error code 1
npm error path /var/www
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c nuxt prepare



не подскажите, что я делаю не так

перед RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force нужно добавить COPY ./packages.json .

Да нет, install там как раз где надо стоит, layer cache же. Просто перед ним надо ещё одну команду COPY поставить...

ну или так. поправил
